# Contravariant interface to common interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, contravariance

I have following contravariant interface and its implementation

```
public interface IMessageSender<in TMessage>
{
    Task SendAsync(TMessage @object);
}

public class MessageSender<TMessage> : IMessageSender<TMessage>
{
    public Task SendAsync(TMessage @object)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have hierarchy of classes that should represent TMessage .

```
public class Base { }
public class Descendant1 : Base { }
public class Descendant2 : Base { }
```

So I have two senders for simplicity

```
var descendant1Sender  = new MessageSender<Descendant1>();
var descendant2Sender  = new MessageSender<Descendant2>();
```

How can I cast these two senders to common interface to pass for example to the method. For example.

```
static void SomeMethod( IServiceBusMessageSender<Base> baseSender)
{
    baseSender.SendAsync(new Descendant1());
}

SomeMethod(descendant1Sender);  //This won't compile because of contravariance
```

Comment: You say it won't compile with IServiceBusMessageSender but that definition isn't in your examples. What is the compilation error message it's giving?

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat `IMessageSender<Descendant1>` as `IMessageSender<Base>` because it is not one, contravariance or not, it requires parameter to be `Descendant1` or `Descendant1`'s descendant.

Contravariance allows to use `IMessageSender<Base>` as `IMessageSender<Descendant1>`, not vice versa. I.e. the following will work (and will result in compilation error if you make the interface invariant):

```cs
IMessageSender<Base> baseSender = ...;
IMessageSender<Descendant1> descendantSender = baseSender;
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zh6vCN)

**UPD**

As workaround you can look into introducing non-generic version of interface and/or some typechecking:

```cs
public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task SendAsync(Base @object);
    bool CanSend(Base msg);
}
public interface IMessageSender<in TMessage> : IMessageSender
{
    Task SendAsync(TMessage @object);
}

public class MessageSender<TMessage> : IMessageSender<TMessage>
{
    public bool CanSend(Base msg) => typeof(TMessage).IsAssignableFrom(msg.GetType());

    public Task SendAsync(TMessage @object) => Task.CompletedTask;

    async Task IMessageSender.SendAsync(Base @object) // explicit interface implementation
    {
        if(@object is TMessage msg)
        {
            await SendAsync(msg);
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception(); // or ignore
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being that `SomeMethod` will check if handler can send the message.

Comment: I edited my answer. I meant that calling someMethod won't compile

Comment: @vborutenko my answer explains why. Contravariance of the interface has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is there any option to do it?

Comment: Why do you think Contravariance has nothing to do with it ? if the interface is covariance it will work

Comment: @vborutenko - while preserving type-safety - no.

Comment: @vborutenko covariance != contravariance. Also this interface can't be covariant over `TMessage` for obvious reasons.